# kmalloc many struct, should I kmalloc them all at a time or respectively

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm reading the source code of a device driver.

It tries to kmalloc 16 `struct foo`

```
spin_lock_bh(&sq->lock);
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        msg = kmalloc(sizeof(*msg), GFP_ATOMIC);
        if (!msg)
                break;
        msg->next = sq->msg_first;
        sq->msg_first = msg; 
        sq->nr_msgs++;
}    
spin_unlock_bh(&sq->lock);
```

So, would it be better `kmalloc(sizeof(*msg) * 16, GFP_ATOMIC)` ? And why ?

Comment: Is this the real source code from a working device driver? A lock is taken on `lock`, however an unlock is done then on a different `spinlock_t` variable `sq->avmi_lock`. That doesn't look correct.

Comment: `would it be better ...` - This is highly depended from your needs. Actually, you are choosing a *type of a container* for messages: **list** (alloc per element, every element needs to contain linkage to the next one) or **array** / **vector** (single allocation for all elements, any element can be accessed by integer index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say anything definitive without seeing the source code. The rationale for doing memory allocation this way may be very different from anything we come up with here.

One reasonable rationale may be this. As you can see, the allocated items are linked together in a singly linked list. This may be just an initial pool of items, that can be expanded or shortened as the driver runs. Some items from the initial pool may get removed and freed at a later time. If you were to allocate this memory in a single allocation, you won't be able to do that. Due to the fact that the items are linked into a linked list, I don't think this will be used as an array as [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) suggests.

I must say that more often than not the rationale can be characterized by a single word: because. Because the author of the code decided that doing it that way was more convenient, or clearer, etc, etc. Unfortunately that happens all the time. As long as those places are not critical (i.e. not in the hot path), it's okay. You can't fix everything.

**EDIT**
As noted in the response below, the allocation is for *up to* 16 items. That might be a deliberate design decision. If the allocation fails at some point, it just breaks out of the allocation loop allocating as many items as it can out of 16. That actually fits the idea that those items may make up an initial pool of *up to* 16 items.

Comment: *"Because"* is also called "design choice".

Comment: Sure. It's just that those design choices are rarely commented in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code attempts to allocate *up* to 16 `struct foo`s.  But if there isn't enough memory then it will still allocate some.  Your suggested change is to attempt to allocate 16 `struct foo`s and to fail if you can't do that.  What if there is only room for some of the allocations?

Also, with one allocation the allocator has to find a contiguous area of memory whereas with multiple it can deal with fragmented memory.